# Count the number of characters between a specific character(Including spaces)

Tags: java, character

I have a File that is in this format:

```
City|the Location|the residence of the customer| the age of the customer| the first name of the customer|
```

I need to read just the first line an determine how many characters are between the sign "|". I need the code to read even the spaces.

This is the code I have:

```
`FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:/test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++){
br.readLine();
}
String line  = br.readLine();

System.out.println(line);

String[] words = line.split("|");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    int counter = 0;
    if (words[i].length() >= 1) {
        for (int k = 0; k < words[i].length(); k++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(words[i].charAt(k)))
                counter++;
        }
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(counter).append(" ");
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
}
```

`

I am very new to java

Comment: Could you then convert the word to a char array and then get the length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String line = "City|the Location|the residence of the customer| the age of the customer| the first name of the customer|";
String[] split = line.split("\\|"); //Note you need the \\ as an escape for the regex Match
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("length of " + i + " is " + split[i].length());
}
```

The output:

```
length of 0 is 4
length of 1 is 12
length of 2 is 29
length of 3 is 24
length of 4 is 31
```

Answer (score 3):

> ***I need to read just the first line an determine how many characters are between the sign "|". I need the code to read even the spaces.***

`String.split` takes a regular expression, so `|` needs to be escaped. Use `\\|` and then

```
words[i].length()
```

will give you the number of characters between the `|` symbols.

Answer (score 2):

First :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++){
  br.readLine();
}
```

This will do nothing since you enter the `for` only if `i` is inferior to 0

Then:

```
if (words[i].length() >= 1) {
```

This `if` is not very useful since you won't enter the next `for` if `words[i].length()` is 0

Finally without testing it, it seems rather correct you may want to test if the character is a letter **OR** `words[i].charAt(k).equals(" ")` for spaces

Answer (score 1):

For better performaces use StringTokenizer instead of String.split(), here an example:

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:/test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line  = br.readLine();

System.out.println(line);

StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
    sb.append(token.length()).append(" "); 
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```